# MySQL calculate yoy (year-over-year) data

Tags: mysql, sql, etl

I have some MAU data with monthly granularity like following:
[image]

I want to get yoy date like:

```
2016-04 yoy MAU = (2016-04 MAU - 2015-04 MAU)/2015-04 MAU  
2016-03 yoy MAU = (2016-03 MAU - 2015-03 MAU)/2015-03 MAU
...
```

I am using MySQL so I don't have window function.
Is there any easier way to achieve what I want?

*The data type:

```
Period                       | varchar(16)  
MAU                          | double
```

Comment: There's a solution here for you.

Comment: YOY MAU in english?

Comment: Have you tried the solution that I provided?

Comment: @CKChen, Have you looked at this solution yet?  I added an explanation a few minutes ago.

Comment: Why oh why is Period a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, periodic data would be stored as a date or as its components, in this case, year and month as separate integer columns.  Since they are represented together as a string here, we need to parse them using SUBSTRING.  The general idea behind the solution is that we need to join the table to itself using an ON clause that "lines up" each row with it's counterpart from one year prior.

This ought to do the trick:

```
select a.Period, a.MAU, b.Period as prior_year, b.MAU as prior_mau,
        (a.MAU - b.MAU) / b.MAU as yoy
    from tbl1 a
    left join tbl1 b on 
        cast(substring(b.Period, 1, 4) as int) = 
        cast(substring(a.Period, 1, 4) as int) - 1 
        and substring(b.Period, 5, 3) = substring(a.Period, 5, 3)   
    order by a.Period asc
```

Here's a second way that's slightly less clear to read but is more efficient (especially if speed is an issue, the table is large, and it's indexed on Period) because it avoids a calculation in the where clause (at least on one side):

```
select a.Period, a.MAU, b.Period as prior_year, b.MAU as prior_mau,
        (a.MAU - b.MAU) / b.MAU as yoy
    from tbl1 a
    left join tbl1 b on 
        a.Period 
        = cast(cast(substring(b.Period, 1, 4) as int) - 1 as varchar(4)) 
        + substring(b.Period, 5, 3)   
    order by a.Period asc
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Assuming `period` is indexed, you would be better off recombining the two parts after you subtracted a year. So that you can do `b.period = (calculation)`

Comment: Yes @MatBailie you're absolutely right.  I actually considered keeping one side of the ON test in its original form (one less calc for SQL to have to do row-by-row -by- row-by-row so to speak) but opted for the visual clarity of more the symmetrical code instead.  Figured with the monthly nature of the data, the length of the table probably isn't an issue.  You know, I think I will go ahead and add that as option 2 (even though, at this point, it seems like this guy is probably never going to circle back and see if anyone answered his question).